# Constructing routes from imported URL constants

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, react.js, dynamic-loading, constants

There is a file created with the project paths in a dictionary.

Example:

```
export const URL = {
 DASHBOARD: '/dashboard',
 SETTINGS: '/settings',
 PROFILE: '/profile',
 PRODUCTS: '/products/'
};
```

And in the file where the routes are used, the urls are imported.  A coworker and I are debating about two ways to write the code.

One of us says that it is more readable import file and do destructuring.

```
import { URL } from './urls.constants';

export default function ROUTES() {
    
  const { DASHBOARD, SETTINGS, PROFILE, PRODUCTS, etc.. } = URL;

  return (
   ...
   <Route path={DASHBOARD} />
   <Route path={SETTINGS} />
   <Route path={PROFILE} />
   <Route path={PRODUCTS } />
   ...
 );
```

The other one of us says that is equal or more readable use the dictionary or enum.

```
import { URL } from './urls.constants';

export default function ROUTES() {

return (
  ...
  <Route path={URL.DASHBOARD} />
  <Route path={URL.SETTINGS} />
  <Route path={URL.PROFILE} />
  <Route path={URL.PRODUCTS } />
  ...
);
```

We know that both options are correct, but what is the best option regarding readability and clean code?

Comment: This is a nitpicky point, but of these two options, the 2nd is clearly better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think that this comes down to developer preference, although, preference aside, you should be programming in a style that adheres to your company/team's style guide (if one exists).

However, I do think that there's an another solution in there, but it depends upon an assumption that you haven't explicitly declared:

Assuming that every URL in your `URL` dictionary needs to be registered via the `<Route>` element, could you not combine `Object.entries()` and `.map()` to dynamically generate the routes?

```js
import { URL } from './urls.constants';

export default function ROUTES() {
  return (
    ...
    {Object.entries(URL).map(([name, path]) => <Route key={name} path={path} />)}
    ...
  );
}
```

Again, this solution depends upon an assumption that I've made on your scenario. But hopefully, either way, it gives you something to think about!

Comment: Yes, that is another solution! and best solution. I think hat this comes down to developer preference but I prefer to avoid duplicating the code. And I think that using desrtucturing it duplicate code